# How to create a linked sheet that checks a box for a day if found and inserts text from another column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to create a sheet in google sheets for my team that shows me what runners have run on what day of the week. Their activities are automatically imported via Zapier with dates from Strava into another worksheet. I would like to have it where when they run and it imports the activity into the sheet, in the other worksheet, it checks off the day of the week for that runner. Ideally, it would reset weekly. Pictures are attached. Thanks!
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLYQb.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkGUQ.png]

[image]

Also, it would be helpful to have it where it shows the total number of miles per runner in a week, and miles per runner per week (like in this picture) [image]

Comment: for weekly reset you will need a script

Comment: [Same question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/164723/45075) posted on WebApps.